# Adding export button in product grid with filter products doesnt work and gives joined field with this alias is already declared error

Tags: error, export, product-grid

I tried to add a export button in the product grid but when exporting the data i was confronted with the error below

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): A joined field with this alias is already declared.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): A joined field with this alias is already declared.
#1 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollection\Interceptor->joinField() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddQuantityFieldToCollection.php:27]
#2 Magento\CatalogInventory\Ui\DataProvider\Product\AddQuantityFieldToCollection->addField() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/ProductDataProvider.php:108]
#3 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider->addField() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php:117]
#4 Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column->addFieldToSelect() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php:70]
#5 Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column->prepare() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php:189]
#6 Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter->prepareComponent() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php:187]
#7 Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter->prepareComponent() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php:187]
#8 Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter->prepareComponent() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php:212]
#9 Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter->getDataProvider() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php:130]
#10 Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter->applySelectionOnTargetProvider() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Export/ConvertToXml.php:134]
#11 Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToXml->getXmlFile() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/GridToXml.php:70]
#12 Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToXml->execute() called at [generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/GridToXml/Interceptor.php:24]
#13 Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToXml\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]
#15 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#16 Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToXml\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#17 Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToXml\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#18 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#19 Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToXml\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#20 Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToXml\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/GridToXml/Interceptor.php:39]
#21 Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToXml\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
```

the code I used was

```
    <exportButton name="export_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">
                    product_listing.product_listing.product_columns.ids
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </exportButton>
```

Comment: did not find the solution but did find a work around using the action buttons for the grid

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Had added a comment to vishant Comment, but my Rep was to low...

I'd like to add my interest to an answer this question because a customer of me would see this feature in his shop.